# Index tableview in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

i have an indexed tableview with 8 arrays like

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:@"GEN"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"1SA"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"EST"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"EZE"]; 
    [tempArray addObject:@"NAH"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"JOH"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"COL"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"REV"];    
    return tempArray; 
}
```

and i get everything right,my problem is when i tap the cell it redirected to the another page with only first array value that is the value inside the `[tempArray addObject:@"GEN"];`and i tap the values in `[tempArray addObject:@"1SA"];`etc etc,i get the values inn the `[tempArray addObject:@"GEN"];`.my DidSelectRowAtIndexPath look like this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ChapterSelectionView *detailViewController = [[ChapterSelectionView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChapterSelectionView" bundle:nil];

    //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
    detailViewController.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
    appDelegate.selectedBookIndex=indexPath.row;


    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    [detailViewController release];
}
```

this is my complete tableview code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    return index % 8;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [books count];
}
```

my viewdidload look like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    l
    appDelegate=(Malayalam_BibleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    s";



     books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSArray *biblearray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Genesis",
                                       @"Exodus",
                                       @"Leviticus",
                                       @"Numbers",
                                       @"Deuteronomy",
                                       @"Joshua",
                                       @"Judges",
                                       @"Ruth", nil];
    NSDictionary *bibledic1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:biblearray1 forKey:@"Countries"];

    NSArray *biblearray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1Samuel",
                            @"2Samuel",
                            @"1King",
                            @"2King",
                            @"1Chronicles",
                            @"2Chronicles",
                            @"Ezra",
                            @"Nehemiah", nil];
    ......etc etc


    [books addObject:bibledic1];
    [books addObject:bibledic2];
      .....etc etc
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [books objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Countries"];
    return [array count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
   // [myBackView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.75 alpha:1]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
    [myBackView release];
    // Configure the cell.
   // cell.textLabel.tag =row*1+col;

    //First get the dictionary object
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [books objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Countries"];
    //NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    //cell.textLabel.text = [books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:18.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;;

    return cell;
}
```

how to get the correct values from tableview cell.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,49,320,480)];
    appDelegate = (Malayalam_BibleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //self.navigationItem.title=[appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]; 
    chapterlabel.text = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
    buttonArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
    //self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg10"]];

        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

    n=[DbHandler mNumberOfChaptersInBook:[appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]];
    int scrollViewHieght=n/6;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,10+34*scrollViewHieght);

    i=1;

    int rowCount=n/6;
    for(int row=0;row<=rowCount;row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
            if(i<=n){
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                button.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
                button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:15.0];
                [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabs"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                //button.frame=CGRectMake(col*52+5,row*34+50,50,32);
                button.frame=CGRectMake(col*52+5,row*34+0,50,32);
                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i++] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                //button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
                button.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
                button.tag =row*6+col;
                [buttonArray addObject:button];
                [scrollView addSubview:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:row*6+col]];
                //[self.view addSubview:button];
                [button release];
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to send section number to the detailViewController. Depending on the section you  have to select the required array.

Comment: in detailVC add one variable for selectedSection, from didSelect method you can get section from, indexPath.section. Pass this value to detailVC, then you can use section value.

Comment: before that can u tell me where u are maintaining the array and how u r accessing it in detailViewController...

Comment: plz look into my question,full code  m using is there n my question.thanks.

Comment: here the code u have given is of first (tableViewController), i need the the details of second(detailViewController)...

Comment: i will edit my question with the second view code plz look at this.

Comment: add these lines just above self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES, in didSelectRowAtindexPath method
NSDictionary *dictionary = [books objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
appDelegate.books = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Countries"];

and check for the expected result.

Comment: it works but missing the second array values ,getting null value in NSArray *biblearray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1Samuel",
                            @"2Samuel",
                            @"1King",
                            @"2King",
                            @"1Chronicles",
                            @"2Chronicles",
                            @"Ezra",
                            @"Nehemiah", nil];
 NSDictionary *bibledic2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:biblearray2 forKey:@"Countries"]; and last arrays

Comment: can u post the screen shots, of first view and second....
The main thing here is u are creating array in first view and accessing in 2nd view. So when any section is selected, pass the array of selected section to app delegate. Remember to alloc NSArray in app delegate